# When binding a const reference to a temporary object, why is the destructor called twice?

Tags: c++, reference, c++98, temporary, temporary-objects

After reading [this article](http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/) on Herb Sutter's blog, I experimented a bit and ran into something that puzzles me. I am using Visual C++ 2005, but I would be surprised if this was implementation dependent.

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Base {
    //Base() {}
    ~Base() { cout << "~Base()" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    const Base & f = Base();
}
```

When run, it displays "`~Base()`" **twice**... But if I un-comment the constructor, it displays it only **once**!

Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**This IS implementation-dependent.**

The standard allows a copy to occur when binding a temporary to a const reference. In your case, VC++ performs a copy only when the constructor is implicitly defined. This is unexpected, but permitted.

[CWG Issue 391 - Require direct binding of short-lived references to rvalues](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/391.html) has fixed this for C++11.

Comment: Interesting.  Will this result in object slicing in some cases?

Comment: where in the standard is this?

Comment: ISO/IEC 14882 8.5.3 paragraph 5